# How to manage temporary variables in Python 3.5?

Tags: python

If i have many functions in python script, can i use same variable name for all those functions? 
If yes, is it efficient? and how? 
or
is it better to use different name for different functions?
Ex:

```
def func1():
    tmp = 1
    ........



def func2():
    tmp = 2
    ........

def funcn():
    tmp = something 
    ............
```

Only problem i could find with this it can get confusing while debugging.

Comment: Every function has it's own scope, so a variable declared in one function would not be visible to any other methods, and would be free after you run out of scope of that function

Answer (score 2):

Each function creates a new scope.  Since you aren't using `global` or `nonlocal`, none of the `tmp` will influence each other in any way so it is *safe* to keep using that name over and over in different functions.

With that said, names like `tmp` are not very descriptive.  Your future self will want to buy your present self some ice-cream if you start using more descriptive names (even for temporary variables).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is "YES". In this case tmp is local to the function scope. so You can use same variable name for all the functions.But that doesn't mean, it stores values in same memory location. So we can not say it is efficient in storage complexity.And if we consider the running time, It does not depend on variable names. It depend on the algorithm and number of inputs.

It is better to use meaningful variable name to each of the function. Because when you are debugging a program, you can identify the code easily.